# How to train Detectron2 model with multiple custom dataset

Tags: python, object-detection, image-segmentation, multiple-instances, coco

I would like to train the detectron2 model with registering multiple datasets

I have extracted my annotations from the different tasks and now I have multiple datasets which we need to be trained together.

```
Datasets Folder
Task1 -- annotations.json
      -- image dir
Task2 -- annotations.json
      -- image dir
Task3 -- annotations.json
      -- image dir
Task4 -- annotations.json
      -- image dir
```

My question is whether we can train the model with multiple datasets.
Can we register multiple coco instances for training?
I would like to train my model on  Task1 Task2 Task3 and test on task4

```
from detectron2.data.datasets import register_coco_instances
register_coco_instances("train", {}," ./Task1/annotations.json", "./Task1/imagedir")
register_coco_instances("Test", {}, "./Task4/annotations.json", "./Task4/imagedir")
```

Or Do I need to combine all the coco instances!

please provide your inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question. Apparently, there is no such method to try the multiple datasets. If you like to combine different datasets then use the [COCO Assitant](https://github.com/ashnair1/COCO-Assistant) library.

Simple step to install is:

```
!pip install coco-assistant
```

Comment: Did you end up using `coco-assistant`? Did it solve your multi-dataset issue?

Comment: Do you need to disclose any affiliation with the creator of that?

Comment: @DV82XL Yes I ended up using coco-assistant. It solved my multiple dataset issue

Comment: @Yunnosch, As coco-assistant is made opensource. I did not have any problem with creator. You can always contact the creator for your specific issues if you have

Answer (score 2):

Actually its possible to train using multiple sets and merge them as described in [GitHub Issue #2544](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/2544)

```
register_coco_instances("my_trainsetA", {}, "train/_annotations.coco.json", "trainA")
...

cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN = ("my_trainsetA", "my_trainsetB", ... )
cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ("my_testsetA", ...)
```

Comment: Just learning to do this for the first time, came across this. I guess what you mean by the ellipses is that you can have a second line like
`register_coco_instances("my_trainsetB", {}, "train/_annotations.coco.json", "trainB")`

Might be a bit clearer to newbies if that line was explicitly there. Thanks!